# Issue initialising dictionaries without using '='

Tags: python, dictionary, twisted

I want to create dictionaries key for all data clients send to server. How to initialize dictionaries without using '=' because I want to append self to list[data] every time connection was made.

I get an error with the following code

```
factory.list = {}
.
.
.
def dataReceived(self,data):
    self.factory.list[data].append(self)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you looking for `self.factory.list.setdefault(data, []).append(self)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use factory.list = collections.defaultdict(list)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to add a list to the dict if it doesn't exist yet:

```
def dataReceived(self,data):
    self.factory.list.setdefault(data, []).append(self)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
def dataReceived(self,data):
    if data not in self.factory.list:
        self.factory.list[data] = []
    self.factory.list[data].append(self)
```